# How to use jquery to slide to a designated area when clicking on an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a project that needs to be clicked on ABOUT and SERVICE to move to the specified article area, js-box1 and js-box2,
but I don’t know which part of the logic is wrong, and it fails to achieve the effect of sliding to the target area. So I would like to ask everyone to help, thank you.

Supplement

I've just been out on his own research can slide to a specified location, but I want to slide blocks are below the black line at about 20px!
But now when I click SERVICE, it will be some distance away from the black line. I don't know how to rewrite the code to meet my needs?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = $(this).attr('href');
    // console.log(target);
    let position = $(target).offset().top - 300;
    // console.log(target,position) 
    $('.content').animate({scrollTop: position}, 1000);
  })
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #ffc20e;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 60px auto;
}
.wrap .header {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrap .header .item {
  margin-right: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.wrap .content {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.wrap .content .box1, .wrap .content .box2 {
  margin: 30px;
}
.wrap .content h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrap .content p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="header">
      <a href="#js-box1" class="item">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#js-box2" class="item">SERVICE</a>
    </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="box1" id="js-box1">
         <h2 class="about">about</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,</p>
    </section>
     <section class="box2" id="js-box2">
         <h2 class="service">service</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla .
uptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla .</p>
     </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're asking why clicking on Service doesn't bring it to just below the black line, that's because there is no more content below the first paragraph below Service, so there is nothing more on the page to scroll to. Try padding that `<div>` so it is `height: 100vh`.

Comment: @Kmoser
Very cool, it turned out to be like this!
But I tried your suggestion, but the effect seems to be unsatisfactory. I don’t know if I wrote it wrong?
Because when I clicked on service, he moved too high to appear below the black line.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height: 490px;` to `.wrap .content .box2` class in css and you good to go!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.item').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let target = $(this).attr('href');
                    // console.log(target);
                    let position = $(target).offset().top +400;
                    // console.log(target,position) 
                    $('.content').animate({scrollTop: position}, 1000);
                });
            })
```

```css
.wrap {
                width: 500px;
                background-color: #ffc20e;
                border-radius: 20px;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 60px auto;
            }
            .wrap .header {
                display: flex;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .wrap .header .item {
                margin-right: 60px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: 600;
            }
            .wrap .content {
                height: 500px;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
            .wrap .content .box1, .wrap .content .box2 {
                margin: 30px;
                height: 490px
            }
            .wrap .content h2 {
                display: inline-block;
                font-weight: 900;
                font-size: 36px;
                background-color: #222;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .wrap .content p {
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 1.5;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
            <ul class="header">
              <a href="#js-box1" class="item">ABOUT</a>
              <a href="#js-box2" class="item">SERVICE</a>
            </ul>
          <div class="content">
            <section class="box1" id="js-box1">
                 <h2 class="about">about</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias,</p>
            </section>
             <section class="box2" id="js-box2">
                 <h2 class="service">service</h2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla .
        uptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla aliquid.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, dolores repellat. Alias, voluptatem? Veritatis dolores suscipit aut dicta nulla .</p>
             </section>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry~ I want to ask you further, how is 490px calculated?
So I will know how to achieve this similar effect in the future

Comment: As @kamoser said, the reason why the page didn't go further down when it scrolled to service section, stopping in the middle of if, is because the service section didn't have a height size big enough to let the page scroll down all the way. By setting the height of `.box2`as 490px It changes that.